# Mostrar/Esconder apenas com CSS

Tags: html, css3

Que CSS eu tenho que fazer para mostrar ou esconder os elementos da `<div id="mostra">` ao clicar no botão Mostrar/Esconder da `<div>` buscar?

Este é o meu HTML:

```html
<div>
  <div id="mostra">
    <input type="text" name="buscar" id="topo-buscar" />
    <button>Buscar</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="buscar">
  <a href="" id="busca">
    <span></span>
    Mostrar/Esconder
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc quer usar apenas css? sem javascript?

Comment: Sim N. Dias, você sabe como se faz?

Comment: Da uma lida aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso utilizando o **Checkbox Hack:**

Basicamente você conecta um `<label>` a um `<input type="checkbox" />` assim ao clicar na `<label>` você muda o *estado* do `<input type="checkbox" />`, *estado* que está relacionado diretamente ao `CSS` de uma `<div>`, assim ao mudar de estado você estará mudando o css aplicado aquela `<div>`.

Fonte: [Show / hide div on click with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975505/7558069)

Mais detalhes sobre o checkbox hack: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

```css
/* Checkbox Hack */
#toggle-1 {
   display:none;
}

label { 
  -webkit-appearance: push-button;
  -moz-appearance: button; 
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* CSS padrão da div */
#mostra {
   display:none;
}

/* CSS quando o checkbox está marcado */
#toggle-1:checked ~ #mostra {
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle-1">
  Clique aqui
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div id="mostra">
    Olá, mundo!
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Outra maneira que penso que funcione e que acaso precise se o botão mostrar/esconder estiver em outro elemento o que impossibilitará de usar o `~` como no exemplo com `:checked`, seria usar o `:target`.

O `:target` funciona baseado na hash da URL da página atual, um exemplo de uso aplicado ao *elemento pai* (pode aplicar ao body, mas vai ficar um pouco mais limitado se tiver mais de um elemento)

um exemplo simples seria:

- Se a URL for algo como `http://foo.bar/pagina`
- Se a URL for algo como `http://foo.bar/pagina#box-1` irá exibir os elementos com `class="mostrar"` dentro do `<div id="box-1"></div>`, irá ocultar o link com `class="show-action"` e irá exibir o link `class="hide-action"` que estiverem dentro do `<div id="box-1"></div>`
- Se a URL for algo como `http://foo.bar/pagina#box-2` irá exibir os elementos com `class="mostrar"` dentro do `<div id="box-2"></div>`, irá ocultar o link com `class="show-action"` e irá exibir o link `class="hide-action"` que estiverem dentro do `<div id="box-2"></div>`

Você poderá criar mais DIVs com mais IDs, é importante lembrar que os IDs em HTML (isso é do HTML e não relacionado ao CSS da minha resposta) não podem nunca se repetir, ID = identidade, ou seja cada um tem o seu.

> O botão "mostar URL" no exemplo abaixo é só pra poder ver a URL dentro do Stack Snippet, pois ele roda em um IFRAME

Um exemplo de teste:

```css
/*
Oculta os elementos com a classe .mostrar
Oculta os elementos com a classe .hide-action
*/

#box-1 .mostrar,
#box-1 .hide-action,
#box-2 .mostrar,
#box-2 .hide-action {
     display: none;
}

/*
conforme a HASH atual:
Mostra os elementos com a classe .mostrar
Mostra os elementos com a classe .hide-action
*/

#box-1:target .mostrar,
#box-1:target .hide-action,
#box-2:target .mostrar,
#box-2:target .hide-action {
     display: block;
}


/*
conforme a HASH atual:
Oculta os elementos com a classe .action-action
*/
#box-1:target .show-action,
#box-2:target .show-action
{
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1">

  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="mostrar">Olá Stack Overflow</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="baz">
      <a class="show-action" href="#box-1">Mostrar</a>
      <a class="hide-action" href="#">Ocultar</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="box-2">

  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="mostrar">Olá Francis Vagner da Luz</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="baz">
      <a class="show-action" href="#box-2">Mostrar</a>
      <a class="hide-action" href="#">Ocultar</a>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="console.log(location.href);">Mostrar url</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar colocar um outro elemento escondido aí no meio do negócio, e usar ele. Algo como;

Cria um elemento display none, um checkbox, e com css você vai pegar o checked ~ #elemento que você quer.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nope" />
<div id="nomeDoDiv">
  Seu conteúdo <br>
  <label for="nope">Esconder</label>
</div>
<div id="nomeDoDiv2">
 <label for="nope">Mostrar</label>
</div>

#nope {
  display: none;
}
#nope:checked ~ #nomeDoDiv {
  display: none;
}
#nope:checked ~ #nomeDoDiv2 {
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nLy9dako/