# Porque o conteúdo não some ou aparece quando eu marco os button radios?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: arial;
        }

        #content {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background: green;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 400px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        #yes:checked #content {
            display: block;
        }
 
        #no:checked #content{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Deseja visualizar o conteúdo?</p>
    <label for="yes">Sim<input id="yes" name="option" type="radio"></label>
    <label for="no">Não<input id="no" name="option" type="radio"></label>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Conteúdo</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No exemplo acima era para quando eu marcar o botão radio com `id="yes"` ele ser exibido e quando marcar o botão radio com `id="no"` ele desaparecer, mas não acontece nada, porque?

Comment: E o JS tá onde meu amigo?

Comment: Não tem! é apenas com o CSS

Comment: A pseudo-class `:checked` é usada quando o elemento for marcado e é o que estou fazendo marcando um elemento para algo acontecer com ele, mas não acontece nada a base é que nem esse exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261970/mostrar-esconder-apenas-com-css

Comment: Neste exemplo que tu me passou, tem uma resposta, ela não te ajuda?

Comment: Não! já resolvi eu deixei uma resposta com a solução, mas valeu!

Comment: Eu vi, deixei um +1 pela resposta haha

Answer (score 2):

Em que parte do código você está implementando essa lógica? Para fazer isso, GERALMENTE se uma linguagem de programação. Nesse caso, a mais usada é JS. Poderíamos implementar o que quer, por exemplo, da seguinte forma:

```js
function verifica(){
  let rdNao = window.document.querySelector('#no').checked 
  let rdSim = window.document.querySelector('#yes').checked
  let conteudo = window.document.querySelector('#content')
  if(rdNao){
    conteudo.style.display = 'none'
  }else{
    conteudo.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: arial;
        }

        #content {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background: green;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 400px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        #yes:checked #content {
            display: block;
        }
 
        #no:checked #content{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Deseja visualizar o conteúdo?</p>
    <label for="yes">Sim<input onchange="verifica()" id="yes" name="option" type="radio"></label>
    <label for="no">Não<input onchange="verifica()" id="no" name="option" type="radio"></label>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Conteúdo</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Mas também é possível usar somente CSS.

Comment: Se é necessário utilizar javascript ou outra linguagem de programação, como nessa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/261985/157404 ele conseguiu fazer somente com CSS ?

Comment: Já foi corrigido...

Comment: Não colega! mas muito obrigado por ter tentado ajudar no meu caso eu só queria com CSS, mas eu já consegui resolver e deixei uma resposta com a solução, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui resolver o problema na seguinte linha:

```
    #yes:checked #content {
        display: block;
    }

    #no:checked #content{
        display: none;
    }
```

Eu estou informando que o elemento com `id="content"` está dentro do elemento `id="yes"` e `id="no"`, isso porque estou usando o seletor decendente e no qual eu devo usar o seletor de irmão já que o elemento `id="content"` está logo após dos elementos de entrada, então alterando a linha fica assim:

```
    #yes:checked ~ #content {
        display: block;
    }

    #no:checked ~ #content{
       display: none;
    }
```

Então os elementos de entradas não podem estar dentro dos paragráfos, nessas linhas também devem ser alteradas se não o seletor de irmão não selecionará o elemento `id="content"`:

**Antes**

```
    <label for="yes">Sim<input id="yes" name="option" type="radio"></label>
    <label for="no">Não<input id="no" name="option" type="radio"></label>
```

**Depois**

```
    <label for="yes">Sim</label><input id="yes" name="option" type="radio">
    <label for="no">Não</label><input id="no" name="option" type="radio" checked="checked">
```

O código por completo fica assim:

```html
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
            <style>
                body {
                    font-family: arial;
                }
        
                #content {
                    width: 400px;
                    height: 400px;
                    background: green;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height: 400px;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    display: none;
                }
        
                #yes:checked ~ #content {
                    display: block;
                }
        
                #no:checked ~ #content{
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Deseja visualizar o conteúdo?</p>
            <label for="yes">Sim</label><input id="yes" name="option" type="radio">
            <label for="no">Não</label><input id="no" name="option" type="radio" checked="checked">
            <div id="content">
                <h1>Conteúdo</h1>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```